# PHP7 override magic method __get not working anymore

Tags: getter-setter, php-7, magic-methods

I used the following method in PHP 5.6 which always worked fine

```
public function __get($name){

            if(!empty($this->_dynamicFields[$name])){
                if(!empty($this->_dynamicData[$name])){
                    return $this->_dynamicData[$name];
                }else{
                    return null;
                }
            }else{
                return parent::__get($name); // That's where the error happens when an array is called in $name
            }
        }
```

Now we upgraded the server to PHP7 and when a script calls the get-method with an array, I get an error

```
$object->$attributes[0]
```

classname.Array is not defined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the [Changes to the handling of indirect variables, properties, and methods](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) in PHP7 which breaks backwards compatibility (see also [Uniform Variable Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax)).

Specifically, in PHP5 your call is interpreted like this:

```
$object->$attributes[0] === $object->{$attributes[0]}
```

However, in PHP7 your call is interpreted like this:

```
$object->$attributes[0] === ($object->$attributes)[0]
```

If you you modify your code to an explicit `$object->{$attributes[0]}` you should see it work as expected again.